# Selección múltiple de menú checkbox en Android

Tags: android, menú, checkbox

Estoy tratando de hacer un menú a modo de filtro para un mapa que te permita seleccionar más de un elemento a la vez como se ve en la imagen. Pero no consigo  que te permita pulsar más de un elemento a la vez sin que se esconda el menú.

Sólo me permite pulsar un checkbox cada vez que abro el menú y es un poco engorroso para el usuario tener que abrir varias veces el menú si quieres seleccionar más de un filtro.

**¿Alguna sugerencia o consejo para solucionar esto?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente (He reducido la lista de opciones para que se más fácil ver el código):

**map_menu.xml**

```
    <menu>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_ciencia"
        android:icon="@drawable/ciencia"
        android:title="@string/filtro_ciencia"
        app:showAsAction="never"

         />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_comercio"
        android:icon="@drawable/comercio"
        android:title="@string/filtro_comercio"
        app:showAsAction="never"
         />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_cultura"
        android:icon="@drawable/cultura"
        android:title="@string/filtro_cultura"
        app:showAsAction="never"
         />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_deporte"
        android:icon="@drawable/deporte"
        android:title="@string/filtro_deportes"
        app:showAsAction="never"
         />
    </group>
    </menu>
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_drawer, menu);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        MenuItem item_ciencia = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_ciencia);
        item_ciencia.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_ciencia, false));
        MenuItem item_comercio = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_comercio);
        item_comercio.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_comercio, false));
        MenuItem item_cultura = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_cultura);
        item_cultura.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_cultura, false));
        MenuItem item_deporte = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_deporte);
        item_deporte.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_deporte, false));
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }else  if (id == R.id.nav_ciencia) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_ciencia, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_comercio) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_comercio, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cultura) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_cultura, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_deporte) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_deporte, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } 

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quita los items del grupo y pon:

```
android:checkable="true"
```

En cada item.

Cuando pones los items dentro de un group, estos se comportan como si solo una opción es seleccionable. El group les da la propiedad (en tu setup) de que todos los items sean seleccionables pero limita a solo un elemento por vez.

Pero los items por separado pueden habilitar ser seleccionables, y si no pertenecen a un grupo no tienen ninguna limitación ni contexto con ningún otro item. En tu caso no necesitas que tus items se comporten como grupo, asi que separarlos es una buena solución.

Tambien puedes inflar una View en el menu, pero es mas complicado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, probaré a ver si eso soluciona mi problema!

Comment: Hola Sander, ¿podrías explicar por qué es la solución? Una respuesta tan breve no ayuda a entender cuál es el problema

Comment: Edite la respuesta. Esta solución si te funcionó?